# How to force 0-count summary cells and add totals to columns and rows (R tidyverse)

Tags: r, tidyverse, summarize

Okay, here is a sample of what my data looks like:

| GRADE_LVL | COURSE_NAME | COURSE_CODE | STUDENT_GENDER | ETHNICITY | OUTCOME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Physics | 03165 | Male | White | Pass |
| 12 | Physics | 03165 | Female | White | Pass |
| 12 | Physics | 03165 | Nonbinary | Black or African American | Pass |
| 9 | Algebra I | 02052 | Female | Multiracial | Pass |
| 10 | Algebra I | 02052 | Female | White | Fail |

I need to report on 3 genders (male, female, nonbinary), and 7 ethnicities (Hispanic or Latino, American Indian or Alaska Native, Asian, Native Hawaiian/Other Pacific Islander, Black or African American, White, and Multiracial).

I am trying to write a function in R that will produce a table of the demographic facts for a set of parameters passed to it. I want the output of the function to produce a tibble that looks like this :

**High School Students Who Passed Algebra I**

|  | Hispanic | Native American | Asian | Black | White | Multiracial | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Male | 0 | 0 | 7 | 2 | 13 | 4 | 26 |
| Female | 1 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 12 | 3 | 20 |
| Nonbinary | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Total | 1 | 0 | 10 | 3 | 26 | 7 | 47 |

*Notes: This contains only dummy values that aren't related to those in my sample data snippet above. I have shortened the column names to save space on the screen.*

Here is the code I have so far:

```
data <- dbGetQuery('secrets')
highSchool = c('09', '10', '11', '12')
passingOnly <- quo(OUTCOME == 'Pass')
algebra1 <- quo(COURSE_CODE == '02052')
ethnicCategories <- factor(c(
                              'Hispanic or Latino', 
                              'American Indian or Alaska Native',
                              'Asian',
                              'Native Hawaiian/Other Pacific Islander',
                              'Black or African American',
                              'White',
                              'Multiracial'
                            ))
genderCategories <- factor(c('Female', 'Male', 'Nonbinary'))

demographicBreakout <- function(filterConditions, gradeLevels) {
      data %>%
      filter( {{ filterConditions }} ) %>%
      filter(GRADE_LVL %in% gradeLevels) %>%
      select(STUDENT_GENDER, ETHNIC_DESC) %>%
      group_by(STUDENT_GENDER, ETHNIC_DESC) %>%
      summarise(COUNT = n()) %>%
      pivot_wider(
        names_from = ETHNIC_DESC, 
        values_from = COUNT, 
        values_fill = 0
      ) %>%
      rename_at("STUDENT_GENDER", ~"Gender")
}

report <- demographicBreakout(
          filterConditions = !!quo(!!algebra1 & !!passingOnly),
          gradeLevels = highSchool
      )
```

This code produces a tibble that looks like this:

| Gender | Hispanic | Asian | Black | White | Multiracial |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Female | 2 | 15 | 2 | 26 | 9 |
| Male | 12 | 23 | 1 | 43 | 11 |

This is looking good so far, but I need to have all demographic categories present in the table even if the count is 0. I tried adding the following code snippet to my `demographicBreakout` function in between the `summarize` and `pivot_wider` statements:

```
      complete(
        ETHNIC_DESC = ethnicCategories,
        STUDENT_GENDER = genderCategories, 
        fill = list(COUNT = 0)
      ) %>%
```

Adding this code caused the following error:

```
Error in `reframe()`:
ℹ In argument: `complete(data = pick(everything()), ..., fill = fill, explicit = explicit)`.
ℹ In group 1: `STUDENT_GENDER = Female`.
Caused by error in `dplyr::full_join()`:
! Join columns in `y` must be present in the data.
✖ Problem with `STUDENT_GENDER`.
```

I have been unable to get this error resolved. In addition to this `complete()` statement, I also need to run something similar on the rows so that `nonbinary` counts appear. On top of all that, I still need to add in the row and column totals.

Any help getting over my current hurdle would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function can be simplified a lot, when we combine the factor conversion idea from Stefan's (now-deleted) answer, and the `.drop = FALSE` argument for the `count()` function:

```
ethnicCategories <- c('Hispanic or Latino', 
                    'American Indian or Alaska Native',
                    'Asian',
                    'Native Hawaiian/Other Pacific Islander',
                    'Black or African American',
                    'White',
                    'Multiracial')
genderCategories <- c('Female', 'Male', 'Nonbinary')

demographicBreakout <- function(filterConditions, gradeLevels) {
  data |>
    filter({{filterConditions}} & GRADE_LVL %in% gradeLevels) |>
    mutate(Gender = factor(STUDENT_GENDER, levels = genderCategories),
            e = factor(ETHNIC_DESC, levels = ethnicCategories)) |>
    count(Gender, e, .drop = FALSE) |>
    pivot_wider(names_from = e, values_from = n)
}
```

Example:

```
demographicBreakout(
          filterConditions = !!quo(COURSE_CODE == '02052'),
          gradeLevels = c('09', '10', '11', '12')
      ) |> print(width = Inf)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 8
  Gender    `Hispanic or Latino` `American Indian or Alaska Native` Asian
  <fct>                    <int>                              <int> <int>
1 Female                       0                                  0     0
2 Male                         0                                  0     0
3 Nonbinary                    0                                  0     0
  `Native Hawaiian/Other Pacific Islander` `Black or African American` White
                                     <int>                       <int> <int>
1                                        0                           0     1
2                                        0                           0     0
3                                        0                           0     0
  Multiracial
        <int>
1           0
2           0
3           0
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked! After reading the documentation from the functions you used, am I correct in understanding that the `pivot_wider()` function automatically returns only the columns mentioned  in the `names_from` and `values_from` arguments, thus eliminating the need for my `select()` statements? I also don't understand how where the value `n` is coming from in the `pivot_wider` `values_from = n` statement you provided.

Comment: re: "pivot_wider() function automatically returns only the columns mentioned in the names_from and values_from arguments, thus eliminating the need for my select() statements" <- not quite! pivot_wider will keep all of the same data ordinarily. You can get it to drop the columns you're not using, using the id_cols parameter

Comment: re: where does n come from? the default value for the count() function is for the count column to be called `n`. You can change the name if you want, as in stefan's code, but it's not needed

Comment: see: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/count.html#ref-examples

Comment: re: your select statements- take a look at `mtcars |> select(cyl) |> group_by(cyl) |> summarise(n = n())`, and compare it to `mtcars |> group_by(cyl) |> summarise(n = n())`. They give the same result, because by default, `summarise(n = n())` (or `count()` will give the number of rows for each group, so the number of columns you have is irrelevant